# Where can a number appear in a selector?

Tags: css, error-handling, css-selectors

When looking into yet another question about a class name starting with a digit that didn't work as expected, the thought suddenly hit me that I don't know what goes wrong.

Here's a simple example:

```css
.123 {color:blue;}
```

```html
<div class="123">This is something 123</div>
```

This doesn't make the output blue.
And the reason is: `.123` is not a valid CSS selector, *because it looks like a number*.

Yeah, but, why? Why would a CSS parser be looking for numbers in a selector? Is there actually a reason for selectors to contain numbers? Can anybody provide an example of such a selector?

Edit: As per the comments, arguments inside parentheses and brackets can be numbers; for example `nth-child(2)` or `[colspan=2]`, so my question is about numbers outside of those.

Comment: Here's a very good article for you: https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

Comment: `:nth-of-type(2)` is an example of a selector containing a number. But the real problem here is that class names are not supposed to start with a digit.

Comment: @VilleKoo That doesn't provide any insights into what goes wrong. I know about the workarounds; not asking about those.

Comment: @GOTO0 Yes, the rules inside parentheses and quotation marks are different; I can edit the question to that effect. But class names consisting of only digits are perfectly valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is probably, that the CSS Selector Spec doesn't allow it and (most) browsers seem to honor this, even though it was probably technically possible to allow leading numbers (or hyphens):

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#lex

A very simplified explanation: A Selector consists of an (optional) type selector (e.g. # for ids, . for classes) a "nmstart" and optional "nmchar" parts. The "nmstart" part doesn't allow numbers, while the "nmchar" part does:

nmstart   [_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape}

nmchar    [_a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape}

Answer (score 1):

As [MattDiMu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997700/1317805) has already pointed out in their answer, the place to find out how selectors should be validated is within section 10 of the CSS Selectors specification: [*The grammar of Selectors*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar), which itself is a clone of the CSS2.2 specification's [Grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/grammar.html) section with a few bits ommitted.

It's in the CSS2.2 specification that we're told *why* numbers are not valid at the start of CSS selectors:

> In CSS1, a class name could start with a digit (".55ft"), unless it was a dimension (".55in"). In CSS2, such classes are parsed as unknown dimensions (to allow for future additions of new units). To make ".55ft" a valid class, CSS2 requires the first digit to be escaped (".\35 5ft")

So in short, it's to avoid confusion. `.1px` is a valid *unit* which could easily be mistaken for a class of "1px", however we can use numbers at the start of a selector like this if we escape it. In the below example, I'm able to target the `div` element whose `class` is "1px" by escaping the 1 within the class selector (as `.\31 px`):

```css
.\31 px {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="1px">Hello, world!</div>
```

Comment: Nice. However, call me dense, but why would a selector need to be checked for dimensions? In what circumstances can `.1px` (the length) be expected at the start of a selector? When can the parser get confused between a length and a class name? One single example of such an instance would be sufficient.

Comment: @MrLister I don't have an official answer to that but I'd guess it would be to allow the parser to easily distinguish between units and selectors. A pretty bad example of this would be media queries: `@media (min-width: .9in)` is perfectly valid as `.9in` is a valid unit, however the parser wouldn't be 100% certain that `.9in` here was intended as a unit instead of it being a class selector erroneously passed in instead.

Comment: @MrLister actually it seems it's probably more to handle backwards compatibility and future implementations. CSS1 allowed ".1blah", but didn't allow ".1in". Rather than continuing that trend, it was decided that ".1blah" should be invalidated, otherwise every time a new unit gets added parsers would have to explicitly handle that exact unit. This leads to a new question: *why did CSS1 differentiate between class selectors and units in this way?* - and that is something I don't know the answer to.

Comment: "why did CSS1 differentiate between class selectors and units in this way?" [It was due to a mistake.](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/1999Jan/0034.html) The intention was always, since CSS1, to disallow digits at the start of a class selector. The CSS1 grammar incorrectly used {name} instead of {ident} to define a class selector, and implementations followed the grammar without realising that it was at odds with what was stated in the prose.

Comment: @BoltClock that's very interesting to know, nice find!

Answer (score 0):

For people who are still interested in this subject, I found one situation where selectors can look like numbers, indeed, where selectors *are* numbers. That is inside a `@keyframes` at-rule.
Example:

```css
@keyframes anim {
 .6% {color:white;}
 100% {color:red;}
}
```

They really are percentages (they won't work without the `%` sign), but they start with a digit or even a period and a digit, so these are actual examples of selectors that could confuse parsers if `.6%` for class `"6%"` would be allowed.